# Cannot install software using Xfce on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, xfce

In Xfce, after launching the Software GUI and trying to install Skype, for example, a window comes up saying 'To continue you need to sign in to Snap store', and it is impossible to proceed further.  I CAN install packages using the default Gnome desktop.

The helpful Snap store prompt replaces the authentication request I used to get in 16.04, and currently get using the 18.04 Gnome desktop, i.e., a prompt to enter your password for authentication.  Help?!

Comment: By the Software GUI, do you mean gnome-software (a.k.a. Ubuntu Software)? You have two choices for how to install Skype, as a gdebi package or as a Snap. If you want the Snap version, have you tried installing via command line in XFCE  e.g. sudo snap install--classic skype?